# Filter document keyup event to specific element without selector

Tags: jquery, events, keyup

I'm dynamically creating elements that don't have a unique handle, so I can't really build a selector to pass to 'on' for filtering.

It also seems 'on' does not accept a jQuery element for the selector, according to the docs. I don't get why not, as the string selector has to be processed (incurring overhead) when I could directly provide the element in question.

Am I missing something obvious here?

```
$(document).on('keyup', elm, function(ev){ console.log( 'keyup on', ev.target ) });
```

Basically, I only want this instance of the event to fire if elm emits a keyup event.

*EDIT*

Forgot some context:

- The element is not in the DOM yet, it is created in memory, and I'm trying to set up all the events there.
- I tried binding the keyup event directly to the element, but it wouldn't fire. Not sure why. I assumed maybe because it wasn't in the DOM yet.
- The element is not an input/textarea, I am relying on contenteditable/user-modify to allow input.

*CONCLUSION*

- The issue was caused by my css. It seems that if the parent has user-modify, the child's keyup event won't fire. To be fair, user-modify should be targeted as possible to avoid DOM editing.

Comment: No, a delegate event listener does not accept an element as the child selector.  That would defeat it's purpose.  If you already have the element selected that you want the delegate to work for, it already exists.  The delegate is not necessary

Comment: If you already have the element, `$(elm).on('keyup', ...)` and carry on with your day

Comment: @Taplar - I tried binding the keyup directly to the element, but that didn't work either. Is that where the issue lies?

Comment: You can bind an event handler to an element not in the dom, if you have a reference to it.  Once it is appended to the DOM, it will still have the event listener.

Comment: @Taplar - Sorry, I omitted essential context: The element is not an input/textarea, I am relying on contenteditable/user-modify to allow input. If I switch it to an input, it works fine.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Ltap0m3u/  It seems like contenteditable elements still trigger keyup events... ?

Comment: @Taplar - Sorry for the wild goose chase; it was my css, see my update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by my css. It seems that if the parent has user-modify, the child's keyup event won't fire. To be fair, user-modify should be as targeted as possible to avoid DOM editing.